# Partition exchange equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm inexperienced with partitioning in SQL Server. I read on oracle-base that there is a concept of `Exchange Partition` where we switch the pointer from 1 partition to another with data. [source: oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition)

I see that `SQL Server` also have concept of [partition switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition#partition-switching). Though I am still reading more about this, I have following questions to raise:

1. Oracle exchange partition and SQL Server partition switching are equivalent to each other?
2. Oracle exchange partition lets switch pointer with data present in partition. Is same true for SQL Server?

This is required for a data warehouse ETL process.

Prod System: SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition

Thanks

Comment: way too Broad....read the docs

Comment: @MitchWheat: I'm reading. Just want someone to briefly answer #2

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` can only switch *to* empty tables/partitions, but it can switch *from* tables/partitions with data, per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) (search on "Switches a block of data in one of the following ways"). Whether that's equivalent to what Oracle does, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert . Let me dig it out in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out solution. For my use case, I used `Schema Swap` methodology.

Syntax: `ALTER SCHEMA <new schema> TRANSFER <existing schema>.<table>;`

Basically, my need was to compare new full load data with existing full load data. [This sqlservercentral post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/149123/) helped me to achieve my goal, further by using SSIS.